# Setting up Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) access on Windows 10 when using a Microsoft Account

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, microsoft-account

I have Windows 10 Professional installed on my desktop, and have attempted to access my desktop remotely via Microsoft's Remote Desktop Protocol. My user account is linked to my Microsoft Account, and I've always had issues authenticating over RDP. The RDP client will ask for a username and password, and neither my account's PIN nor my Microsoft Account's password work.

For reference, I have tried logging in from another Windows 10 system, and also using the Remmina Remote Desktop Client on a linux device.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to some other posts here on superuser, I finally found a solution that allows me to authenticate using my Microsoft Account's credentials, and access my desktop remotely (using Remmina in this case).

Here are the other questions/answers I got this solution from:

- https://superuser.com/a/1423901/965962
- https://superuser.com/a/1633513/965962

Apparently, if you only ever login to your Windows 10 device using a PIN (for example), Windows will not locally store a hash of your Microsoft Account password. When you attempt to login via a Remote Desktop client, your PIN will not work as a password. The solution is to lock your local account, and then login using your Microsoft Account password (while connected to the internet), so that Windows can locally store a hash of the password.

Here's the steps I took to get it working:

1. Lock your device (from start menu, or press `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` and click `Lock`)
2. Choose your account to unlock, and click `Sign-In options`, and select the `Microsoft account password` button. This should change the login prompt to "Password" (instead of "PIN" for example)
3. Enter your Microsoft Account password, and unlock your device.
4. Access your device remotely using a Remote Desktop client, entering your Microsoft Account's email as the RDP user, and your Microsoft Account's password as the RDP password.

Even though this question/solution has been posted before, it took some digging to actually find the solution that worked for my situation. Hopefully others find this useful!

Comment: Thanks for the tip - in 2024 this did not work for me. The signin process for the Hello PIN has changed somewhat and I could not use the password without using the Authenticator app. 

After I signed in using steps 1-3 here, Remmina just keeps rejecting the email/password.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection program `mstsc.exe`, go to the Advanced tab then click the checkbox for "Use a web account to sign in to the remote computer". When you connect a window will open to allow you to enter your credentials for your Microsoft account.

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced tab in the Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection program]