# Credential issue with Windows Remote Desktop to ARM (Windows Dev Kit 2023) - Can't Complete Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11, arm

I have one of the ARM-based Windows Dev Kit devices (aka Project Volterra, runs Windows 11). I sign on as the same user in which I am signed on to my primary desktop (Intel, Windows 10) and Surface Pro (Intel, Windows 11). This is a Microsoft account associated with my gmail address, not an otherwise managed account.

Under any of the following scenarios, I will not be prompted for credentials when connecting via RDE between machines:

- Desktop to Surface Pro
- Surface Pro to Desktop
- ARM to Desktop
- ARM to Surface Pro

However, if I attempt to connect to the ARM device from either the Surface Pro or the Desktop, I am prompted for my password (for user "MicrosoftAccount\redacted@gmail.com") which I correctly provide, but it is then rejected.

I did the usual check of "can't connect to RDE" things such as verifying firewall settings, verifying that the user has access via RDE (which of course it does because it is the only account on the device), etc.

I have tried to do some research on this, but the very slim number of issues I can find related to ARM and RDE tend to be related to Azure ARM instances, and the discussed resolutions did not seem terribly applicable.

While I would love someone to say, "I had this precise problem and you just..." however, I am at this point quite open even to "it might be..." sort of answers. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: I did come across this setting under Accounts>Sign-in Options which I disabled. I thought possibly that might relax the policy somewhat.

[image: Shot of disabled requirement for Windows Hello sign-ins]

Unfortunately, even after restarting the ARM machine, this did not result in any different behavior.

One final comment: I am not looking to set up an additional local account on the machine. Even if it is a satisfactory work-around, it is not the actual solution.

Edit 2:
I had already attempted to use my PIN when prompted for the account password. This does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, I did find a resolution. While looking at related questions, I came across, [this one from 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1026277/windows-10-remote-desktop-credentials?rq=1). See specifically the top-rated comment on the accepted answer.

Although I couldn't imagine a reason why my MSFT account could be out of sync between the two machines (it has not changed recently), I thought I would give a try to the suggestion of forcing a resync of the password. Open a command shell (cmd) and then:

`runas /u:MicrosoftAccount\redacted@gmail.com cmd.exe`

It then prompts you for your password (at the command line, not with a Windows dialog). Entered it correctly and it launches a new instance of cmd. I exited both and then switch the KVM to my desktop and attempted to connect again. I am writing this answer via the RDE session that was established.
 
[Microsoft Support answer discussing the forced sync process.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/force-refresh-sync-of-microsoft-account-password/d7bddb0d-663f-4775-9593-ce21b17ca800)